# Connect Multiple FTPs and SQL DBs Together From Different Server (Share Resources)

Tags: mysql, database, ftp, cluster-computing, grid-computing

This is a challenging question, but will still ask it. I know nothing is impossible. Impossible simply means not discovered yet.

What I would like to do is connect all my FTPs and SQL DBs from my 10 servers and pool them all together to combine the resources and create a share resource environment. Therefore creating a ftp and sql cluster. I do not want to purchase any software. Just wondering if there is some method maybe in PHP. I dont want to clone my sites db to the 10 servers, but wondering is there a way to bridge 10 sql dbs together over 10 servers to create a super computer like environment?

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) is an Open-Source solution.
[Distributed FTP Daemon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drftpd/) seems to be a promising project.